# How to get the value of checked checkbox in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on this snippet. Why am I not able to get the `value` of any checked checkbox with class `.shapes`?

```js
document.getElementsByName('shapes').onclick = function() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('shapes')[0].value;
  console.log(checkbox.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="js-shapes">
  <span class="ib">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="circle" id="cb-circle"> <label for="cb-circle">Circle</label>
        </span>
  <span class="ib">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="diamond" id="cb-diamond"> <label for="cb-diamond">Diamond</label>
        </span>
  <span class="ib">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="square" id="cb-square"> <label for="cb-square">Square</label>
        </span>
  <span class="ib">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="triangle" id="cb-triangle"> <label for="cb-triangle">Triangle</label>
        </span>
  <span class="ib">
          <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="all" id="cb-all" checked> <label for="cb-all">all Shapes</label>
        </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and use forEach method to check which checkbox was `clicked` using addEventListener with `change` function in it.

**Edit:** If you want to get the value of checkbox when checked you can `checked` property and then display its value.

**Live Demo**

```js
let allCheckBox = document.querySelectorAll('.shapes')

  allCheckBox.forEach((checkbox) => { 
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      console.log(event.target.value)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="js-shapes">
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="circle" id="cb-circle"> <label for="cb-circle">Circle</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="diamond" id="cb-diamond"> <label for="cb-diamond">Diamond</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="square" id="cb-square"> <label for="cb-square">Square</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="triangle" id="cb-triangle"> <label for="cb-triangle">Triangle</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="all" id="cb-all" checked> <label for="cb-all">all Shapes</label>
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lost AlwaysHelping but is there any way to also check the state of the checkbox? I mean for example console log only when the element is checked? not on both state?

Comment: @Behseini Answer edited. WOrking on checked state and showing value when checked.

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns collection, you have to loop through them so that you can attach the event to them individually. Also, I will suggest you to use `addEventListener()` to attach event:

```js
document.getElementsByName('shapes').forEach(function(chk){
  chk.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.checked){
      console.log(this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="js-shapes">
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="circle" id="cb-circle"> <label for="cb-circle">Circle</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="diamond" id="cb-diamond"> <label for="cb-diamond">Diamond</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="square" id="cb-square"> <label for="cb-square">Square</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="triangle" id="cb-triangle"> <label for="cb-triangle">Triangle</label>
  </span>
  <span class="ib">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shapes" class="shapes" value="all" id="cb-all" checked> <label for="cb-all">all Shapes</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lost Mamun but is there any way to also check the state of the checkbox? I mean for example console log only when the element is checked? not on both state?

Comment: @Behseini, you can check the `checked` property based on which you can log the value, updated the answer, please check:)